Screen manager unable to navigate to a new page
I am using multiple screens on kivy. In a screen called Riddles I have Riddlepage having buttons in it. I try to go to another screen by clicking on any of these buttons using the function navigate defined in the mainapp. I used b.bind(on_press=lambda x:MainApp().navigate("Page2")
Here's part of the code

class Page2(Screen):
    name="Page2"
class Riddles(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
class Riddlepage(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.pp = open("riddle.txt", "r")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.spacing = dp(5)
        self.pos_hint = {"top": 1}
        for line in self.pp.readlines():
            b = Button(text=line, size_hint=(.8, None), pos_hint={"x": .1}, height=(dp(40)),background_color=(0,0,1))
            b.bind(on_press=lambda x:MainApp().navigate("Page2"))
            self.add_widget(b)
        self.pp.close()
class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        with open("profile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            self.info = file.readlines()
        self.sm=ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(Page1(name="Page1"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Riddles(name="Riddles"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Coursewindow(name="Coursewindow"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Ancienwindow(name="Ancienwindow"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Level(name="Level"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Levels(name="Levels"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Corrections(name="Corrections"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Past_papers(name="Past_papers"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Page2(name="Page2"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Page3(name="Page3"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Profile(name="Profile"))
        return self.sm
    def navigate(self,p):
        self.sm.add_widget(Page2())
        self.sm.current="Page2"
        return self.sm
MainApp().run()


The problem is with your line:
b.bind(on_press=lambda x:MainApp().navigate("Page2"))

because the call to MainApp() creates a new instance of MainApp which is not a part of the MainApp instance that is displayed on your screen. The fix is to call the navigate() method of the correct MainApp instance. You can do that by using the get_running_app() method of App. Like this:
b.bind(on_press=lambda x: App.get_running_app().navigate("Page2"))

